# Webview showing a white blank page

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview for showing Flipkart website in my application.

Everything is working fine as needed except one thing:

when I click on BuyNow button, select variant view gets visible.

This view comes for 1 sec and then show the white blank page.

Is there any setting i need to enable in webview to show this types of view?

I had already gone through many questions on Stackoverflow but nothing helped me.

I tried setting webchromeclient and below methods on webview with no success.

```
shopping_webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                    shopping_webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
                    shopping_webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                    shopping_webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                    shopping_webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                    shopping_webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    shopping_webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                    shopping_webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                    shopping_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

                shopping_webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
                shopping_webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                shopping_webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
                shopping_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: please check with another website link may be this issue on the website.

Comment: the same website is working fine in Chrome web browser on phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 webviewLink.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webviewLink.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webviewLink.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webviewLink.loadUrl(postlink);

            webviewLink.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    // TODO show you progress image
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO hide your progress image
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
            });
```

load the Url with this way it's work for me in the same app..

Comment: I dont want to sent user to outside app. above code will send user to chrome browser.

and as I said above in question on clicking buynow only select varient view gets visibility URL remains the same.

Comment: I am doing the same with no luck. :-(

Comment: I check the Flipkart link with the above code the Couldn't load memtrack module error could occur because of emulators configurations problems. please try with the android device.

Comment: I am trying on android device

Answer (score 0):

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

```
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(_URL);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: sometime url not working in emulator but it will work on real device.

Comment: I am not testing on the emulator, I am testing it on the real device.

and I am already doing what you suggested.

Comment: can You share snapshot?did you try with amazon,ebay or other shoping site link?

Comment: I got it, the problem is with the XML part and not the java part.

Need to replace the hight with matchparent instead of wrapcontent.